# Rename files and adding a prefix according to groups

Tags: linux, rename, prefix

Let's say I have files in side a folder named

```
abc001.jpg
abc002.jpg
abc003.jpg
abc004.jpg
abc005.jpg
.
.
.
acb999.jpg
```

Let's say group1 is

- abc001.jpg
- abc002.jpg
- abc005.jpg
- abc010.jpg

and group2 is

- abc003.jpg
- abc004.jpg
- abc009.jpg
- abc111.jpg

I want to add a prefix like `gr1` and `gr2` according to the group they belong to, like:

- gr1abc001.jpg
- gr1abc002.jpg
- gr1abc005.jpg
- gr1abc010.jpg
- gr2abc003.jpg
- gr2abc004.jpg
- gr2abc009.jpg

I need to do it using a shell script.

Comment: How do you define the group? Is it the `group` as defined in the permissions of the file?